# Multi-threading program to print numbers from 1 to 50?

Tags: java, multithreading

im trying to write a program in which two threads are created and the output should be like 1st thread prints 1 and the next thread prints 2 ,1st thread again prints 3 and so on. im a beginner so pls help me clearly. i thought thread share the same memory so they will share the i variable and print accordingly. but in output i get like thread1: 1, thread2 : 1, thread1: 2, thread2 : 2 nd so on. pls help. here is my code

```
class me extends Thread
{
public int name,i;
public void run()
{
    for(i=1;i<=50;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Thread" + name + " : " + i);
        try
        {
            sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("some problem");
        }
    }
}
}
public class he
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    me a=new me();
    me b=new me();
    a.name=1;
    b.name=2;
    a.start();
    b.start();
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Yes, why do you want to do this ? Is this a homework problem or some random thing you wanted to try ?

Comment: Well, your variable `i` is a local variable that is only available inside the loop and inside the thread that is exeuting the loop. However, are you sure you want your two threads to alternate in writing? You could achieve this by having one thread triggering the other and vice versa, but you'll basically make your program run sequentially. Alternatively, you could let your two threads write in no particular order, e.g., Thread1 writes 1, Thread1 writes 2, Thread2 writes 3, ... **Edit**: Sorry, actually your `i` isn't a local variable, but you'd need to update it atomically.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you want to do is:

- Write all numbers from 1 to 50 to `System.out`

  - without any number being printed multiple times
  - with the numbers being printed in order
- Have this execution be done by two concurrent threads

First, let's look at what is happening in your code: Each number is printed twice. The reason for this is that `i` is an instance variable of `me`, your `Thread`. So each `Thread` has its own `i`, i.e., they do not share the value.

To make the two threads share the same value, we need to pass the same value when constructing `me`. Now, doing so with the primitive `int` won't help us much, because by passing an `int` we are not passing a reference, hence the two threads will still work on independent memory locations.

Let us define a new class, `Value` which holds the integer for us: (**Edit:** The same could also be achieved by passing an array `int[]`, which also holds the reference to the memory location of its content)

```
class Value{
  int i = 1;
}
```

Now, `main` can instantiate **one** object of type `Value` and pass the reference to it to both threads. This way, they can access the same memory location.

```
class Me extends Thread {
  final Value v; 
  public Me(Value v){
    this.v = v;
  }
  public void run(){
    for(; v.i < 50; v.i++){
    // ...
  }

  public static void main(){
    Value valueInstance = new Value(); 
    Me a = new Me(valueInstance); 
    Me b = new Me(valueInstance); 
  }
}
```

Now `i` isn't printed twice each time. However, you'll notice that the behavior is still not as desired. This is because the operations are interleaved: `a` may read `i`, let's say, the value is 5. Next, `b` increments the value of `i`, and stores the new value. `i` is now 6. However, `a` did still read the old value, 5, and will print 5 again, even though `b` just printed 5.

To solve this, we must **lock** the instance `v`, i.e., the object of type `Value`. Java provides the keyword `synchronized`, which will hold a lock during the execution of all code inside the `synchronized` block. However, if you simply put synchronize in your method, you still won't get what you desire. Assuming you write:

```
public void run(){ synchronized(v) {
  for(; v.i < 50; v.i++) {
  // ...
}}
```

Your first thread will acquire the lock, but never release it until the entire loop has been executed (which is when `i` has the value 50). Hence, you must release the lock somehow when it is safe to do so. Well... the only code in your `run` method that does not depend on `i` (and hence does not need to be locking) is `sleep`, which luckily also is where the thread spends the most time in.

Since everything is in the loop body, a simple `synchronized` block won't do. We can use `Semaphore` to acquire a lock. So, we create a `Semaphore` instance in the `main` method, and, similar to `v`, pass it to both threads. We can then acquire and release the lock on the `Semaphore` to let both threads have the chance to get the resource, while guaranteeing safety.

Here's the code that will do the trick:

```
public class Me extends Thread {
    public int name;
    final Value v;
    final Semaphore lock;

    public Me(Value v, Semaphore lock) {
        this.v = v;
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            lock.acquire();
            while (v.i <= 50) {
                System.out.println("Thread" + name + " : " + v.i);
                v.i++;
                lock.release();
                sleep(100);
                lock.acquire();
            }
            lock.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("some problem");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Value v = new Value();
        Semaphore lock = new Semaphore(1);
        Me a = new Me(v, lock);
        Me b = new Me(v, lock);
        a.name = 1;
        b.name = 2;
        a.start();
        b.start();
    }

    static class Value {
        int i = 1;
    }
}
```

Note: Since we are acquiring the lock at the end of the loop, we must also release it after the loop, or the resource will never be freed. Also, I changed the `for`-loop to a `while` loop, because we need to update `i` before releasing the lock for the first time, or the other thread can again read the same value.

Answer (score -1):

First off you should read this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html.
Secondly the class member variables are not shared memory. You need to explicitly pass an object (such as the counter) to both objects, such that it becomes shared. However, this will still not be enough. The shared memory can be cached by the threads so you will have race-conditions. To solve this you will need to use a [Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) or use an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

Comment: I agree. If Java 1.5+ is being targeted I'd go with an `AtomicInteger`. You then get atomicity and you can use synchronization on that object and use notify and wait for signalling to keep the threads in lock step with one another (so that the output remains interlaced)

Answer (score -1):

Check the below link for the solution. Using multiple threads we can print the numbers in ascending order

http://cooltekhie.blogspot.in/2017/06/#987628206008590221

Comment: There are a number of problems with this if only because the first thread to acquire the lock never surrenders it. That's bad enough but it then waits on being notified which will never complete because the notifying thread (if not the main thread never relinquishes the lock. Fixing that still won't do because there is absolutely no guarantee that threads will be called round-robin as the question asks.

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers. You should summarize relevant parts of the article that you've included so that your answer by itself is sufficient to answer the question. This helps to ensure that answers are still useful even if the link becomes dead at some point in the future.